# Line breaks invoking PowerShell from MSBuild

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I'm trying to call a PowerShell script from my MSBuild script. When I collapse the following into a single line, it runs, but when I leave it like this, I get the error below. In case it matters, I'm kicking off the MSBuild script from a BAT script.

```
<Exec Command="powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted 
           -Command &quot;&amp; Invoke-Command 
             -ComputerName &apos;$(Server)&apos; 
             -ScriptBlock { 
                &amp;install.ps1 
                -serviceName &apos;$(ServiceName)&apos; 
                -exePath &apos;$(ExePath)&apos; 
                -computerName &apos;$(Server)&apos; 
             } &quot;
  " />
```

> '-Command' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>     operable program or batch file.
>
> '-ComputerName' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>     operable program or batch file.
>
> '-ScriptBlock' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>     operable program or batch file.
>
> & was unexpected at this time.

I copied the XML from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files) as a starting point, I checked that all whitespace are plain space characters, I tried adding a space to the end of each line, I tried making sure there was only a single space at the beginning of each line with none at the end, and I tried both Windows and Unix line endings. None of those made any difference, so I'm not sure what could be happening.

After some feedback, I've tried adding `` ` `` and `^` to the end of each line except the one with `/>`, and neither allowed the script to run.

Comment: Add `^` at the end of each line.

Comment: @PetSerAl That didn't work either

Comment: Add additional `^` before `&quot;` and before `&amp;`.

Comment: @PetSerAl That did it! Write it up as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PetSerAl's comments, I was able to fix it like so, by adding `^` at the end of each line, and before each double-quot and ampersand:

```
<Exec Command="powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted ^
           -Command ^&quot;^&amp; Invoke-Command
             -ComputerName &apos;$(Server)&apos; ^
             -ScriptBlock { ^
                ^&amp;install.ps1 ^
                -serviceName &apos;$(ServiceName)&apos; ^
                -exePath &apos;$(ExePath)&apos; ^
                -computerName &apos;$(Server)&apos; ^
             } ^&quot;
  " />
```